# SQL get value from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want just get value from xml.
my code looks like :

```
   DECLARE @XML xml
set @XML = (select InXML from   ServiceBrokerQueueFault where id=29140)
select @XML

select
x.Rec.query('./nrZamowienia').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'NrZamowienia'
FROM @XML.nodes('/powiadomienie')as x(Rec)
```

any my @XML displays :

```
<ns2:powiadomOZdarzeniu xmlns:ns2="http://cyfrowypolsat.pl/interfejsy/umowy/zamowieniaom/v1/Zdarzenie">
  <metryka>
    <uzytkownik>om-system</uzytkownik>
    <system>OM</system>
    <data>2017-10-25T15:36:23.006</data>
    <uid>BAC27CDB-9888-46DD-BDE3-B3752852C50C</uid>
    <nazwaKwalifikowanaInterfejsuDoWywolaniaZwrotnego>{http://cyfrowypolsat.pl/service/wyrocznia/om/v1/notification}sendCallback</nazwaKwalifikowanaInterfejsuDoWywolaniaZwrotnego>
  </metryka>
  <powiadomienie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ZapisanoDaneUmowy">
    <nrZamowienia>Z2017-528-700-701</nrZamowienia>
    <zdarzenie>ZAPISANO_DANE_UMOWY</zdarzenie>
    <dataRejestracjiZdarzenia>2017-10-25T15:36:23.006</dataRejestracjiZdarzenia>
    <dataZmianyStatusu>2017-10-25T14:37:20.857</dataZmianyStatusu>
    <typProcesuSprzedazowego>SERVICES_CHANGE</typProcesuSprzedazowego>
    <dataWejsciaWZycie>2018-03-28T00:00:00.000</dataWejsciaWZycie>
    <kanalRealizacji>APS</kanalRealizacji>
    <nrUmowy>U2017-759-557-275</nrUmowy>
  </powiadomienie>
</ns2:powiadomOZdarzeniu>
```

How can i just get in select value of ?

```
<nrZamowienia>Z2017-528-700-701</nrZamowienia>
```

I tried like this too like this

```
DECLARE @XML xml
set @XML = (select InXML from   ServiceBrokerQueueFault where id=29140)
select @XML

select
x.Rec.query('./nrZamowienia').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'NrZamowienia'
FROM @XML.nodes('powiadomOZdarzeniu/powiadomienie')as x(Rec)
```

but it doesn't works . Can somemne help me? I know there a lof of examples but still can't get it and write good path i think for this xml.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL server, MySQL?

Comment: I'm using mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is alright except for the namespace.  One way is `with xmlnamespaces`:

```
; with  xmlnamespaces(
         'http://cyfrowypolsat.pl/interfejsy/umowy/zamowieniaom/v1/Zdarzenie' as s)
select  x.Rec.query('nrZamowienia').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'NrZamowienia'
from    @XML.nodes('s:powiadomOZdarzeniu/powiadomienie') as x(Rec)
```

Another way is to `declare namespace`:

```
select  x.Rec.query('nrZamowienia').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'NrZamowienia'
from    @XML.nodes('declare namespace 
           s="http://cyfrowypolsat.pl/interfejsy/umowy/zamowieniaom/v1/Zdarzenie";
           s:powiadomOZdarzeniu/powiadomienie') as x(Rec)
```